Hamiltonian form for Yang-Mills theory
For trying to convert a Lagrangian system to Hamiltonian form, I've seen references to two different methods for dealing with constraints; the Dirac-Bergmann method (see reference here) or the Faddeev-Jackiw method (here). However, I haven't been able to find either method applied to (classical) Yang-Mills theory to put it in Hamiltonian form.
My own (amateur) attempts at this have not met with success:

as the reference above describes Jackiw's method, it would involve solving the non-abelian version of the Gauss constraint $D_i E^i = j^0$ (too difficult, at least for me, due to the presence of the gauge-covariant derivative)
attempting to perform the Dirac-Bergmann algorithm, starting with the primary constraint $\pi_0=0$ as in electromagnetism, I get the non-abelian Gauss law as a secondary constraint as expected, but then checking the consistency conditions generates more constraints: I get that $$\{D_iE^i-j^0,H_P\}=-ig[A_0,D_iE^i-j^0]+g^2[A_j,[A_k,F_{jk}]]$$ so that $[A_j,[A_k,F_{jk}]]$ must also weakly vanish, and then this goes on to generate even more complicated constraints (at this point I start to get lost in the calculations and haven't been able to complete the algorithm).

So my question is, is it possible to put $SU(N)$ Yang-Mills theory in Hamiltonian form? If so, what does it look like?

Light-front approaches have been pretty successful at that, see e.g. Section 2 of https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9705477 Appendix E discusses Dirac-Bergmann.
